# VirtualPC Trac appliance

Tags: virtualization, trac

Does anybody know a Trac appliance for VirtualPC? I have seen many in vmware, but i prefer virtualpc.

Comment: Are you talking about a pre-configured virtual machine image that includes an installation of the Trac bug-tracking/project management software?

Comment: yes, some like http://bitnami.org/stack/trac but in virtualpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about that would be to pick one of the vmware appliances and [convert the VMWare image to a VirtualPC image](http://blog.brawney.com/2009/01/convert-vmware-vmdk-to-virtual-pc-vhd.html).  (Disclaimer: I have not tried to do this.)

Comment: I have found this link, it worked.